# Inspection Not Ready ( 02, 02 heater, cat)

Tags: ford, emissions, f-150

2006 Ford F150
Battery was unplugged before car was purchased. I bought it and put 300+ miles on it and still see those 3 sensors not ready. No codes.

- Replace all 02 sensors?
- Diagnose with mech for possible wiring issue?
- Keep driving more?

Thanks!